# Do pots of Nolzur's Marvelous Pigments act like a consumable item that is fully consumed when activated or can a pot be activated multiple times?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, resource-consumption

The popular interpretation of Nolzur's Marvelous Pigments is that a pot can be opened and only a portion of the paint can be used with the remainder being saved for later use. Often discussions of the item specifically mention tracking the amount of paint used. This gave rise to the idea that you could bypass the 25 gold value limitation per painting by painting a single coin worth less than 25g multiple times.

An alternative explanation is that since the pots of pigments are consumable it should be treated as a consumable magic item. A pot of paint is activated and applied to a surface (like oil). The area a pot can cover acts as limitation on the maximum size and is treated similar to over healing on a potion (you cant drink half a potion if you don't need the full amount).

The relevant text from the DMG says:

> Some items are used up when they are activated. A potion or an elixir
> must be swallowed, or an oil applied to the body. The writing vanishes
> from a scroll when it is read. Once used, a consumable item loses its
> magic.

The magic item says:

> The paint flows from the brush to form the desired object as you
> concentrate on its image.
>
> Each pot of paint is sufficient to cover 1,000 square feet of a
> surface, which lets you create inanimate objects or terrain
> features--such as a door, a pit, flowers, trees, cells, rooms, or
> weapons-- that are up to 10,000 cubic feet. It takes 10 minutes to
> cover 100 square feet.
>
> When you complete the painting, the object or terrain feature depicted
> becomes a real, nonmagical object. Thus, painting a door on a wall
> creates an actual door that can be opened to whatever is beyond.
> Painting a pit on a floor creates a real pit, and its depth counts
> against the total area of objects you create.
>
> Nothing created by the pigments can have a value greater than 25 gp.
> If you paint an object of greater value (such as a diamond or a pile
> of gold), the object looks authentic, but close inspection reveals it
> is made from paste, bone, or some other worthless material.

Comment: **Historical note:** In earlier editions of the game, the description of Nolzur's Marvellous Pigments specified the total value of items that could be created by a pot of pigments (2,000 gold pieces), rather than the maximum value of any individual item.

Answer (score 11):

You wrote:

> A pot of paint is activated…

The magic item description doesn’t say anything about activating a pot, so nothing about the rules for activating an item apply to the pot. You don’t activate and consume the pot, paint just flows out of the brush:

> The paint flows from the brush to form the desired object as you concentrate on its image.

There’s just nothing to support the interpretation that the entire pot is single use.

Comment: So is the assumption that everything is reusable unless it says otherwise? It doesn't specify that you can close the pot again, or activate it multiple times. I think this is right, but I am not 100% sure on the reasoning. For example wands talk about charges, so they are not reusable without that line even though they aren't actually consumables (is consumable a specific tag anyway?).

Comment: @SeriousBri I don’t really understand what you’re asking, but I think you’re making it more complicated than it is. Magic items do what they say they do, and most of them are pretty obvious.

Comment: @SeriousBri: You could argue that paint will dry out eventually after unsealing a pot, if you want to put a limit on many small uses of the same pot over a long period of time, but the rules don't say this so it would be basically homebrew.  You could also say that some amount is left on the brush so there's a fixed overhead to every separate use.  But again, the rules don't make it complicated that way, so it's purely up to the DM to make stuff up if they want it to work differently from what's written.  But painting 25 separate gold coins in one sitting wouldn't be affected by either.

Comment: I agree 100% with magic items doing what they say they do, but this one says you activate it, paint flows and it can cover an area. It makes no mention of multiple activations so reading it as single use is possible. I was asking if there is anything actually supporting it being multiple use because you seem to be starting with the assumption that everything is multiple use unless otherwise said, but is that true?

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not arguing about paint drying, I am just asking why the base assumption is multiple use. The spell does not specifically say multiple use, just that it can be activated and does x. It is perfectly reasonable to think that is a one time only activation and then the magic is gone.

Comment: @SeriousBri “it can be activated” Where? Where does it say this?

Comment: Actually I was misreading the line in your reply when I wrote that part, but the point I am trying to make is the same, it says you get X pots and that the pots can do y area, it doesn't talk about single use or multiple use at all so I was just wondering where your default assumption came from.

Comment: For what it is worth I do think you are right that they are, or at least should be, multiple use. I just can't actually see anything concrete one way or another that lets me actually agree with this answer.

Comment: @SeriousBri Exactly, it can do Y area. If I have done less than Y area, then I still have paint left.

Comment: On lots of questions can is taken as optional, so you 'can' do X area, but if you choose not to it doesn't necessarily mean you can come back later. I see a good case for open pot, magic happens, end. I don't agree with that case, but I do see it and can't see any actual rules which really sell me one way or another. I can't even write a contradictory answer because it's so unclear to me

Comment: @SeriousBri: The argument for the multi-use reading being the default is that it's described as **pigment** that has magical effects when painted onto 2d surfaces.  A sensible default assumption is that "a magic X" behaves like a mundane X in every way excepts those specified (or directly implied, e.g. a magic lantern might not have a reservoir for oil if the light is magic.)  We know from real life that if you don't use all the pigment in a pot, there will be some left that you can use later.  So unless there's some language about "opening" a pot, it's just painting that activates the magic.

Comment: @SeriousBri: But yeah, on second look, I can see that as a possible reading of "*Each pot of paint is sufficient to cover 1,000 square feet of a surface, ...*" as meaning one pot is only good for one painting.  On factor in support of it not just being normal paint is "*The paint flows from the brush to form the desired object as you concentrate on its image.*"  After seeing that, I can't just dismiss your alternate reading as unnecessary complication; it does seem like a valid reading if your DM wants the paints to work that way in their campaign.

Comment: @SeriousBri: Critical Role's campaign 2 is a good example of just how far you can stretch the paint if you only mark off total area painted: a door here and there, or painting out just the hinges on other doors, gives you a near-unlimited resource for getting through stuff, costing only time.  And/or for conjuring small items.  (It was a great fit for the character in that case, so it worked well as part of her ongoing toolkit, rather than as a consumable that would be gone in a few uses, and would be a stressful decision to ever use.)

Comment: @PeterCordes it makes me happy that at least one person understands the point I am trying to make 

Comment: @SeriousBri: Perhaps we can get a hint from looking at its design in previous editions, where as GMJoe comments, the value limit was specified differently.  It was in the 3.5e SRD, and the text in https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Marvelous_Pigments matches a quote in a forum post.  *... The user can create normal weapons, armor, and any other mundane item (including foodstuffs) whose value does not exceed 2,000 gp.* could be interpreted as total value per pot, which might imply you have to use the whole pot at once, otherwise painting breastplates or suits of full plate could pay for itself.